# Update cross table with new values delete if not in array anymore

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cross table that stores the membership of a member in a group with the following structure:

rs_member_group(uniqueid, groupid) with both together as a primary key.

I have the following two entries:

```
uniqueid     groupid
100110001    1
100110002    1
100110003    1
```

Now I want to update this and get an array with only two of these three members because one got deleted out of the group. I have 100110001 and 100110002. What I want to do it doing nothing with the two members but delete the 100110003 entry. Is there a good way to do it? I could also just delete all entries and insert them again but I want to store a date time when the member got added to the group.

So after the update I want the table to look like this:

```
uniqueid     groupid
100110001    1
100110002    1
```

I am doing this with PHP and a MySQL database.

Comment: perhaps I didn't understand you correctly, but why not just `delete from table where column = value`?

Comment: I don't want to delete the entries that comes with the "new" array again. I want to delete the entries that are NOT in the new array anymore.

Comment: Can you show how you construct the array?

Comment: Well that array is just a JSON object containing the members: "members":[{"uniqueid":"100110001"},{"uniqueid":"100110002"}]. The I have a foreach loop where i can do my stuff.